# Accessing an enum that is within a class that is within a namespace

Tags: c++, class, enums, namespaces, scope

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 using g++ as a compiler, and I've run into a problem trying to use the Alignment enums to place my GUI objects appropriately. Here is the relevant code from guichan's graphics.hpp:

```
...
00053 namespace gcn
00054 {
00055     class Color;
00056     class Font;
00057     class Image;
00058 
00094     class GCN_CORE_DECLSPEC Graphics
00095     {
00096     public:
00100         enum Alignment
00101         {
00102             LEFT = 0,
00103             CENTER,
00104             RIGHT
00105         };
...
```

Here is the line I am using to attempt to access the CENTER.

```
gcn::Graphics::Alignment _align = gcn::Graphics::Alignment::CENTER;
```

There error I receive is:

> error: ‘gcn::Graphics::Alignment’ is not a class or namespace

I hope someone can give me a hand, I've searched everywhere for a similar problem, but to no avail.

Comment: `gcn::Graphics.Alignment`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, or at least the different ways I have tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enumeration names are injected into the enclosing namespace unless you use `enum class` which was introduced into C++ with the 2011 revision. If you use plain `enum`, you just qualify the names with enclosing scope:

```
gcn::Graphics::CENTER
```

Comment: +1, Note: Declaring a different enumeration type (like `enum Position { LEFT=1,...}` using the same symbol(s) (`LEFT` in this case) is likewise not legal until the aforementioned feature of C++11 (`enum class`) of this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dietmar! :D Edit: I'll bear that in mind, thank you Craig.